# Blender random crash when viewing or hiding an object in scene

Tags: objects, 3d-view, viewlayers

I'm experiencing an annoying bug/crash multiple times a day.

I've had a look at the crash log but can't figure out what the problem is,

Can anyone have a quick look and let me know what they think?

Much appreciated in advance!!

Thanks

Is this the crash report?

## backtrace

Exception Record:

ExceptionCode         : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Exception Address     : 0x00007FF6C30C575D
Exception Module      : blender.exe
Exception Flags       : 0x00000000
Exception Parameters  : 0x2
Parameters[0] : 0x0000000000000000
Parameters[1] : 0x0000000000000720

**THE FULL FILE BELOW**

## Blender 3.3.1, Commit date: 2022-10-04 18:35, Hash b292cfe5a936

bpy.data.objects["AMDU Jacket"].hide_viewport = True  # Property
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].(null) = False  # Property
bpy.context.object.hide_viewport = True  # Property
bpy.data.objects["RN Bunny Skirt"].hide_viewport = False  # Property

## backtrace

Exception Record:

ExceptionCode         : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Exception Address     : 0x00007FF6C30C575D
Exception Module      : blender.exe
Exception Flags       : 0x00000000
Exception Parameters  : 0x2
Parameters[0] : 0x0000000000000000
Parameters[1] : 0x0000000000000720

Stack trace:
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C30C5480  sculpt_update_object
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C30C4B60  BKE_sculpt_update_object_for_edit
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C3C3EEE0  SCULPT_stroke_modifiers_check
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C3C3BA40  SCULPT_cursor_geometry_info_update
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C3BEF880  paint_cursor_sculpt_session_update_and_init
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C3BEFFA0  paint_draw_cursor
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C3373E00  wm_draw_window_onscreen
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C3373670  wm_draw_window
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C33730C0  wm_draw_update
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C334C450  WM_main
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C24412A0  main
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C8562D10  __scrt_common_main_seh
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Threads:
Thread : 000039ac
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 000028d8
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 000027b4
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00002520
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00001388
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 000024f8
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 000019b0
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00003404
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00003808
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00001c50
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00002d48
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00003d8c
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 000042d0
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00002130
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 000014e4
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00003410
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F6380  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C90F5B90  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C2603A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (**cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved**::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 000033a8
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
nvoglv64.dll        :0x00007FFE16E7D0D0  DrvValidateVersion
nvoglv64.dll        :0x00007FFE16C130FC  Symbols not available

Thread : 00002870
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2F940  ZwWaitForMultipleObjects
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC3456E0  WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC3456C0  WaitForMultipleObjects
nvoglv64.dll        :0x00007FFE16EB2100  DrvPresentBuffers
nvoglv64.dll        :0x00007FFE16EB2100  DrvPresentBuffers
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 0000313c
win32u.dll          :0x00007FFEACB6ACE0  NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx
USER32.dll          :0x00007FFEAEB44F50  MsgWaitForMultipleObjects
nvoglv64.dll        :0x00007FFE16E7D0D0  DrvValidateVersion
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00001350
win32u.dll          :0x00007FFEACB6ACE0  NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx
USER32.dll          :0x00007FFEAEB44F50  MsgWaitForMultipleObjects
directmanipulation.dll:0x00007FFE8BD6AD00  DllGetClassObject
directmanipulation.dll:0x00007FFE8BD6AD00  DllGetClassObject
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00004150
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2F940  ZwWaitForMultipleObjects
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC3456E0  WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
:0x000001BFFA20FEC0  Symbols not available

Thread : 00002ab0
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 000010a4
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 0000149c
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00004034
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 000038cc
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00001bcc
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00001478
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00001610
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00001a88
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00003c04
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 000019ac
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00000930
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00002a28
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 000023a8
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00001414
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 000042dc
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00003558
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2EE70  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC319A70  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFEA8CDD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 00004310
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE32A40  NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDC56F0  RtlClearThreadWorkOnBehalfTicket
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 0000336c
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE2F940  ZwWaitForMultipleObjects
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC3456E0  WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC3456C0  WaitForMultipleObjects
nvcuda64.dll        :0x00007FFE05FBC744  Symbols not available

Thread : 00001508
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE329E0  ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDF9740  RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFEAC356950  SleepConditionVariableSRW
MSVCP140.dll        :0x00007FFEA8C12820  std::_Winerror_message
MSVCP140.dll        :0x00007FFEA8C12BB0  Cnd_wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C4A57B10  ccl::Session::run_wait_for_work
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C4A56ED0  ccl::Session::run_main_render_loop
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C4A582B0  ccl::Session::thread_render
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C4A58690  ccl::Session::thread_run
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C789B970  ccl::thread::run
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6C41B93A0  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void * __ptr64 (__cdecl*)(void * __ptr64),ccl::thread * __ptr64>,0,
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFEAC1E92C0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

Thread : 000010b4
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEE32A40  NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDC56F0  RtlClearThreadWorkOnBehalfTicket
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFEAD8D2430  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFEAEDEDF90  RtlUserThreadStart

## Python backtrace

Comment: overall:  "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION" in routine " sculpt_update_object".  (not that I know!)

Comment: There are no developers here. First update to 3.3.2 and if it still does it report it as a bug via Blender's Help > Report a Bug menu.